Winget ls shortening ids
I'm not sure if this is a winget question or a PowerShell question. Basically, winget ls output is too wide for the shell window, so it cuts off the column with ellipses. I tried ooutputing to a file or using start-process, but the resulting file also contains the shortened versions of th ids.
How can I get the full Ids of the apps?


Not powershell.

1. First of all use this command to see if you have installed "Microsoft.WinGet.Client" module:
PS C:\Users\User> Get-InstalledModule -Name Microsoft.WinGet.Client

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
1.8.1791             Microsoft.WinGet.Client             PSGallery            PowerShell Module for the Windows Package Manager Client. Due to https://github.com/PowerShell/PSResourceGet/issues/85 this modul…

2. If you have installed it continue to the Step 3, if you don't have the module installed use this command to install:
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.WinGet.Client

3. Try to use this command to see the full Id:
Get-WinGetPackage | Select Id

Example of output:
> Get-WinGetPackage | Select Id

Id
--
7zip.7zip
ShareX.ShareX
CrystalDewWorld.CrystalDiskInfo
Logitech.Options
Microsoft.VSTOR
Notepad++.Notepad++
Microsoft.OneDrive
WinMerge.WinMerge
MSIX\Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension_1.1.861.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_2.1.1803.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackes-ES_22621.54.227.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable_126.0.2592.113_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.OneDriveSync_24141.714.2.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.Paint_11.2404.1020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.PowerToys.FileLocksmithContextMenu_1.0.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.PowerToys.ImageResizerContextMenu_0.81.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.PowerToys.PowerRenameContextMenu_0.81.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.RawImageExtension_2.3.1221.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2405.32.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.SecHealthUI_1000.25873.9001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MSIX\Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp_22403.1401.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe


If you need more info here you have a github discussion about your question and the powershell gallery page of the module used:

Github Discussion

PSGallery: Microsoft.WinGet.Client


Regards!
